# how do you navigate to a internal function definition which is declared in a header in eclipse C/C++ CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse, function, header, definition

I tried using f3 key and ctrl+f3 key, but I could not navigate to the definition. I have a library

I read a few posts and concluded that _function_name tells compiler that "This function is an internal function, but the code for it is somewhere else." But how can we know where the function is defined.

My CASE:- I am working on libgcrypt. There is a function declared in g10lib.h which is defined somewhere that I need to find out and called in cipher.c, there is also a statement

```
/* Internal function.  Lookup a module specification.  */
gcry_module_t _gcry_module_lookup (gcry_module_t entries, void *data,
                gcry_module_lookup_t func);
```

in g10lib.h. My query is how can we know where the definition of _gcry_module_lookup is.

Comment: What's wrong with looking up the actual file, and then opening it in Eclipse or any IDE?

Comment: I suspect `internal` in this context means the library does **not** export the function. So you need to pull the librarie's sources fro somewhere to be able to have closer look at it. If using a library it normally only comes in binary format together with a C header file to describe the API it exposes.

Comment: @Alex : Imagine you have a library with thousands of files, given that you have a file (abc.c) with a function declaration and its definition is not in that file (abc.c). Now how would you manually locate the file with that function definition among those huge number of source files?  
PS: I could not navigate through function call hierarchy even in eclipse, that is why I posted it here.

Comment: @alk: Yes, "internal" in the sense, it is a library owned function and we cannot manipulate it AFAIK. I do have the library source files including header files and tried to navigate through them. In eclipse we do have an option like 'F3' or 'ctrl+F3' to navigate through function hierarchy and their references automatically, but i could not navigate through that internal function. I could not find it(funciton definition) manually too. So is there a way to see the definition of the internal functions automatically or manually?

Comment: What about `grep`ing through the library's source directories. Like `cd <lib-source-top-level-dir>; grep <func-name> * -rw`

Comment: @annunarcist I imagine in that case it may be a shortcoming of the library its self for not providing detailed info. However, the parsing functionality you're expecting (and I am willing to assume is possible, because I've seen it in other IDEs) is a luxury you shouldn't take for granted. What I am saying, is that if that function is so important to you, you will eventually have to dig up the actual header/implementations. Have you searched around Eclipse's preferences, anything that has to do with parsing files, indexing functions, etc? What's in g10lib.h? Also what do keyboard shortcuts say?

Comment: @alk Excellent!! grepping the string worked and shows the occurrences and call hierarchy in a library in no time.....thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Alex yes, i too have seen in many of the IDEs which support parsing of function calls, but since this library has internal functions(_xxx_Xxx) we could not parse through that internal function because it is library reserved function. And i too think it is a backlog of this library. Even in g10lib.h, it takes us to those internal functions declarations and cannot parse from there. Anyhow now if I grep the string as alk suggested, i am able to get the files that contain that string in much lesser time. thanks for your time & help.